# Boost async: which completion condition to use with async_read on a socket?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using **Boost's `async_read` method** to read from a socket (see code below).

Wireshark shows that **packets of various size are received** on the socket port, **some with size between 256B and 512B** (we only focus on these packets below).

- When I use `transfer_all()` completion condition, the handler function is **never called**, as if all packets were buffered forever and never actually read.
- On the opposite, if I use for instance `transfer_at_least(8)` as a completion condition, the handler function is **called twice per packet**, once with 256B of data, then once with the remainder. This I can understand (I guess the condition is checked every 256B or something).

What I want is to **have the handler called once for each packet with the full data**, but I cannot find how to do this.

Note: this question ([boost::asio::read with completion condition boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1) won't read until EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406796/boostasioread-with-completion-condition-boostasiotransfer-at-least1-wo)) seems to say `transfer_all` is the way to go, but what is my issue here?

---

```
// Extract of .h file
class ClientSocket
{
    ...
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer_;
    ...
}

// Extract of .cpp file
void ClientSocket::start_read()
{
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, input_buffer_, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(8), boost::bind(&ClientSocket::handle_read, this, _1));
};

void ClientSocket::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        const auto buffer = input_buffer_.data();
        std::size_t size = input_buffer_.size();
        // ---> the value of 'size' here show the issue
        
        // Copy data
        ...

        // Keep reading
        start_read();
    }
}
```

Comment: `transfer_all` will keep reading until the stream closes, if you don't close the stream it'll never complete. In general I wouldn't worry about it, just accept the data as it comes in and only if you benchmark and find that splitting packets is a bottle neck for your application try to fix it

Comment: Ok. So you mean I should use `transfer_at_least` and somehow merge the packets parts manually?

Comment: Your application shouldn't care about packets, TCP is a stream based protocol and there is no guarantee how the data will be packetised

Comment: What Alan said. You have to know your application protocol. That will inform what completion condition works. If it's just plain receiving octet streams, choose a fixed buffer size and the read will automatically complete when the buffer is full.